# Delete From sqlite not working

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Hello I’m making a budget application that will allow you to look at expeances entered and if need be delete them I can call the method run thro it and it wont have a issue but when I check to see if it worked it hasnt I’ve tried but cant figure out why this doesn’t work. I use a alert dialog to confirm that they want to delete.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    this);

                // set title
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("DELETE "+position);

                // set dialog message
                alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage("Are you sure you whant to delete Expeance "+position)
                    .setCancelable(false)

                    .setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            String[]    po = position.split(" ");
                            String  date = po[0];
                            date = date +".tar.gz";
                            entry.open();
                            entry.deleteByDate(date);
                            entry.close();
                        recreate();
                        }

                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            // if this button is clicked, just close
                            // the dialog box and do nothing
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

                    // create alert dialog
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                    // show it
                    alertDialog.show();
```

and here is the code for the method

```
public SQLiteDatabase deleteByDate(String date2) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE2, KEY_DATE + " =?", new String[] { date2 });
            ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE4, KEY_DATE + " =?", new String[] { date2 });
            return ourDatabase;

        }
```

Comment: DId you open it in read write mode?

Comment: yes i have ourDatabase as writable ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `Pattern.compile` for replacing **"/"**  with **"-"** as instead of `date.replace("/", "_")`:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/");
    String  date = po[0];
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(date);
    date = matcher.replaceAll("_");

    date = date +".tar.gz";
    //your code here....
```

Comment: that has nothing to do with the issue im having the date variable is being change properly my programs just not removing the varible for some reason

Comment: this is related to your issue because maybe possible replace is not working and you are trying to match wrong string in delete . so you first conform replace is working or not using logs

Comment: @newProgrammer : may be you have any other issue but this is one issue in your current code as i known

Comment: i have checked this and it changes it properly which is why i said it is not the issue. ive even had the database open looking at the change in the variable while looking at how it is in the database and it matches up its just not deleteing it for some reason

Comment: @newProgrammer : i have checked on my side if string is date ="06/08/2012" then date.replace("/", "_") is not working on my end it's not replacing  "/" with "-".

Comment: ok i owe you a apology. i have edited my code so that i dont need to do the replace method anymore and its haveing no issues and is deleteing every time i fill very foolish